# Queue class with enqueue and dequeue

Tags: swift, queue

I am just learning swift and tried to make a queue class with enqueue and dequeue.

- The node holds the data for each element
- The enqueue adds an element to the "queue"
- The dequeue deletes the first element in the queue and returns the data
- Head and Tail are references to node elements, which also tells if the queue is empty when they are `nil` (null)

Now I am wondering, have I done this correctly, both the theory and can the code be improved in Swift (used to code in Java)?

```
class Queue {

    class Node {
        // variables
        var data: String
        var prev: Node?

        init(data: String){
            self.data = data
        }
    }

    // variables
    var head: Node?
    var tail: Node?

    func enqueue(e: String){
        if head == nil && tail == nil {
            head = Node(data: e)
            head?.prev = nil
            tail = head
        } else {
            let temp = Node(data: e)
            tail?.prev = temp
            tail = temp

        }
    }


    func dequeue() -> String{
        let result = head?.data

        if head === tail {
            head = nil
            tail = nil
        } else {
            head = head?.prev
        }
        if (result == nil){
            return "empty"
        }
        return result!
    }

}
```

Testing the program:

```
var q: Queue
q = Queue()

q.enqueue("One")
q.enqueue("Two")
q.enqueue("Three")

print(q.dequeue())
print(q.dequeue())
print(q.dequeue())
print(q.dequeue())
```

Output:

> ```
> One
> Two
> Three
> empty
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct as far as I can see. However, there are some
things which can be improved or simplified.

Let's start with the `class Node` definition:

- Strictly speaking, `data` and `prev` are *properties.*
- `prev` is – as I understand it – a pointer to the node that was added *after* this one, so I would call it `next` instead.
- The class should be private because it is not indented to be 
  used outside of `Queue`.
- `data` should be a *constant* because it is not mutated after the
  creation of a node (attributions go to @Feldur who noticed that in
  a comment).
- Minor note: There should be a space before curly braces.

Then we have:

```
private class Node {
    // properties
    let data: String
    var next: Node?

    init(data: String) {
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

Consequently, `head` and `tail` are private properties as well:

```
// properties
private var head: Node?
private var tail: Node?
```

The `enqueue()` method can be simplified. `head` and `tail` are both
`nil` or not, so there is no need to check both. Here it makes sense
to check the tail via *optional binding*, so that a new node can be
appended if the list was non-empty, or a single-node list created
otherwise:

```
func enqueue(e: String) {
    let node = Node(data: e)
    if let lastNode = tail {
        lastNode.next = node
    } else {
        head = node
    }
    tail = node
}
```

The `dequeue()` method returns the string "empty" if the queue is 
empty. This is a "magic string" and makes it impossible to store the
string "empty" itself in the queue. Swift *optionals* were make
for this very purpose: The method should return an optional `String?`
which is `nil` if the queue is empty.

The method can be simplified in a similar manner as `enqueue()`.
Now we check the initial node via optional binding. Note that there
is no forced unwrapping (`!`)  anymore, which should generally be
avoided:

```
func dequeue() -> String? {
    if let firstNode = head {
        head = firstNode.next
        if head == nil {
            tail = nil
        }
        return firstNode.data
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

In your test code, the queue variable can be defined and initialized in
a single statement:

```
var q = Queue()
```

Since `dequeue()` now returns an optional, we can remove elements in
a loop like this:

```
q.enqueue("One")
q.enqueue("Two")
q.enqueue("Three")

while let s = q.dequeue() {
    print(s)
}
```

Finally: There is nothing in the implementation which is particular
to strings. You can make the class *generic* so that it can be used
with other data types as well. Only minor modifications are 
necessary:

- Replace `Node` by `Node<T>` (and move it outside of `Queue`, as 
  Swift currently does not allow nested types in generic classes).
- Replace `Queue` by `Queue<T>`.
- Replace `String` by `T`.

Then it looks like this:

```
private class Node<T> {
    let data: T
    var next: Node?

    init(data: T) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

class Queue<T> {

    private var head: Node<T>?
    private var tail: Node<T>?

    func enqueue(e: T) {
        let node = Node(data: e)
        if let lastNode = tail {
            lastNode.next = node
        } else {
            head = node
        }
        tail = node
    }

    func dequeue() -> T? {
        if let firstNode = head {
            head = firstNode.next
            if head == nil {
                tail = nil
            }
            return firstNode.data
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
var q = Queue<Int>()

q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(2)
q.enqueue(3)

while let i = q.dequeue() {
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: Great idea with generic classes, I am still learning Swift and this helped a  lot!

Comment: 1. Why classes vs structure, which are generally preferred?

Comment: 2. Why not make the generic version conform to SewuenceType?

Comment: 3. Why are the properties of Node var's when they never need to be mutated?

Comment: @Feldur: Re #1: That is quite a broad question. In this particular case, `Node` is a class because you need  *references* to the nodes in `head` and `tail`. `Queue` *could* be made a struct, but then you have to implement copy-on-write semantics, so that a copy of a queue is really independent and does not share the list of nodes.

Comment: @Feldur: Re #2: Yes, one could add conformance to SequenceType if you want to enumerate all queue elements. For a plain FIFO you just need `enqueue` and `dequeue`.

Comment: @Feldur: Re #3: The `next` property needs to be a variable because it is mutated when a node is appended. But `data` should be a constant, that is a good point! I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate the replies. They make good sense.